# What is the host that must be targeted in the manifest to build a calendar add-in?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am playing with quick start guide to build custom add-in for outlook mail. Here the link: [quick start guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial).

In the documentation host type targeted are:

- Document (Word)
- Database (Access)
- Mailbox (Outlook)
- Notebook (OneNote)
- Presentation (PowerPoint)
- Project (Project)
- Workbook (Excel)

It seems is not possibile to build an add-in for calendar. But in calendar is possible to add a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook add-ins are supported in both read and compose modes for appointments. See here for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-or-set-the-time-of-an-appointment.